# REST check server status with 1XX code

Tags: rest

What I want to do is before consuming a service, check if the server is up. Because I have to make different things depending on that response.

It is ok if I make a GET that returns a 1XX code(e.g. 100 Continue) and then consume the service?
What's the common way to solve this?

Comment: If a server is down, you won't even get a `100 Continue` but some kind of timeout.

Comment: yes, thats what I'm doing right now to manage this. I just want to know if it a good way of solving the problem.